# how to auto change background color and text color of browsing websites in Chrome browser for custom visibility?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, visibility

I work long hours in front of computer doing market research work. Is there anyway, you can automatically change most of the white color background of the webpages directly to black and text color to white to improve visibility in Google Chrome browser?

BTW, I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extension: Change Colors  - 1.3 
link http://www.chromeextensions.org/appearance-functioning/change-colors/#.UyY6nfmSxmw

what i do

Firefox 2   Firefox screen capture as described in the page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small extension to change text/background color for chrome browser.

With mouse dragging, page color will change in real-time.
So you can adjust and adjust ... until you feel satisfied.

Here is the online installation link from chrome webstore.

[babu color](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/babu-color/dkabogmdcebincpnhjkblipnceehimch)

It is pretty simple to use... no need any instructions.
But if you really need a guide, then 
have a look here:

[Text Help & Video Demo](http://www.palitranslate.com/babucolor/)